# Docker container does not communicate with others in same docker network(bridge)

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, nginx

I'm trying to set the environment for web server on amazon web server.
I want to use django, react, nginx and they are running on each docker container.

Belows are the command for running docker container.

```
sudo docker run --name django-server
  -it -d -p "8000:8000"
  --volume=$(pwd)/trello-copy-django-src:/backend/trello-copy
  django-server

sudo docker run --name nginx-server
  -d -p "80:80"
  --volumes-from react-server
  nginx-server
```

I did not specified a custom docker network bridge and I checked that they are on same default bridge by typing `$ docker inspect bridge`.

```
[{
  "Name": "bridge",
  ...,
  "Containers": {
    "...": { "Name": "django-server", ... },
    "...": { "Name": "react-server", ... },
    "...": { "Name": "nginx-server", ... },
  }
}]
```

So, I expected the react code down below works. But it worked only at my laptop, which has exactly same docker structure of aws.

```
...
const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/');
...
```

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
`127.0.0.1:8000/api/:1`

What am I doing wrong?

---

These are codes in my `settings.py` file of django.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True # only for dev
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS=True # only for dev
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',
)
```

The CORS message was `App.js:10 Fetch API cannot load django-server:8000/api/. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`.

I think it's different issue, and then django and CORS are not really problem... am I right?

---

I found that the 'localhost' of  ajax `await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/');` means client side(browser) indeed.

Do I have to use server's public IP in there?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call by `127.0.0.1`. Instead, you need to use name of the running container. Like this:

```
const res = await fetch('django-server:8000/api/');
```

Comment: Thank you for relpy. I've tried but CORS problem is issued. So I just add 'http://' and I got this error. ```GET http://django-server:8000/api/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED```

Comment: if you are facing CORS issue, then you need to resolve it from django server, not from docker

Comment: I've appended more detail on the question... please notice that.

Comment: can you create a network, then add the dockers and finally add the name of the network to `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`?

Comment: I've created a bridge named 'my-network' and moved all containers into that bridge. But `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` makes error like this. `?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin 'my-network' in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST is missing  scheme or netloc
        HINT: Add a scheme (e.g. https://) or netloc (e.g. example.com).`

Comment: **It seems worked.** Maybe the docker network was not working well.